# How do you edit the "Posted To Category" part of a Wordpress post to 'linkify' the entire phrase instead of just the category?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey guys, I have a pretty basic question (even though I know the title sounds confusing) which is best explained as follows.  This code is what I currently have:

```
<?php if (!is_page()): ?><?php ob_start(); ?><?php printf(__('Posted to %s', 'kubrick'), get_the_category_list(', ')); ?>
```

Which generates this HTML code:

```
Posted to <a href="http://www.example.com/category/" title="View all posts in Category" rel="category tag">Category</a>
```

As you can see, the category is 'linkified' by this code, however I would like the entire phrase to be the anchor text for the link, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/category/" title="View all posts in Category" rel="category tag">Posted to Category</a>
```

How would I modify the original PHP code to include the "Posted to" text in the hyperlink's anchor text?  Much appreciated!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_the_category()` and `get_category_link()` functions as follows:

```
<?php
    foreach(get_the_category() as $category)
        echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'" title="View all posts in Category" rel="category tag">Posted to '.$category->cat_name.'</a> ';
?>
```

However you may like to consider what happens when a post is in more than one category: your original code will show a list of category links separated by commas (e.g. "Posted in foo, bar, qux"), whereas this code will show "Posted in [name]" for each category (e.g. "Posted in foo Posted in bar Posted in qux").

It should also be noted that this answer does not use WordPress's [`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) function to translate the resulting text where appropriate: you may like to consider how best to support non-English speakers.

Also, it's not necessary to close and reopen PHP tags after each contiguous command - just separate them with semicolons.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much for such a quick response!  Each post is only in one category, so there's nothing to worry about there.  This worked magnificently and has substantially improved my site!  Thanks a lot buddy, I couldn't have asked for a better response.  :)